# What is causing systemd circular dependency?

Tags: systemd

**Why do I get a dependency error? I only specify what to run before, and no not say what to run after. Yet there is a dependency loop.**

I tried to add a service to systemd, and now have an ordering error.

## Error messages

Extract from `/var/log/boot.log`

```
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping local-fs-pre.target
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping systemd-ask-password-plymouth.path
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping paths.target
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping cryptsetup.target
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping local-fs.target
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping local-fs-pre.target
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping systemd-ask-password-plymouth.path
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping cryptsetup.target
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping systemd-pcrphase-sysinit.service
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping local-fs.target
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping local-fs-pre.target
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping plymouth-start.service
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping cryptsetup.target
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping local-fs.target
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping local-fs-pre.target
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping systemd-ask-password-plymouth.path
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping cryptsetup.target
[  OK  ] Finished plymouth-read-write.service - Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Finished systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service - Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization...
         Starting systemd-update-utmp.service - Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP...
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping systemd-ask-password-plymouth.path
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping cryptsetup.target
```

## The service file

`cat ./remove-bad-yoga-keyboard-device.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=disable the internal keyboard
Before=keyboard-setup.service 
Before=console-setup.service 
Before=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/local/remove-bad-yoga-keyboard-device
WorkingDirectory=/local
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

## The installer

`cat setup-disable-yoga-keyboard`

```
#!/bin/bash
cwd="$(pwd)"
cd "$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"
this_dir="$(pwd)"

mkdir -p /local
cd /local
cp -t . "${this_dir}"/remove-bad-yoga-keyboard-device

cd /etc/systemd/system
cp -t . "${this_dir}"/remove-bad-yoga-keyboard-device.service

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable remove-bad-yoga-keyboard-device.service
```

Some playing with  `systemd-analyze` is showing a conflict with `shutdown.target`. However when I analyse this target, it shows that it conflicts with everything. My guess is shutdown is special, and the analyser does not understand it. And that `shutdown.target` is not the problem. This leaves me with the question, what is.

After some more playing I removed the rule `Before=keyboard-setup.service` and `systemd-analyze verify` has passed it, and it boots without error.

**But why do I get a dependency error? I only specify what to run before, and no not say what to run after. Yet there is a dependency loop.**

---

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
`/local` is a directory on the root partition

Comment: Is `/local` on a LUKS partition or something like that which would require password input?

Comment: @mulu No I already had a problem when it was on `/home` (probably because running before mounting `/home`), so now it is on the root partition.

Answer (score 2):

Because it does not include the setting `DefaultDependencies=no`, your `remove-bad-yoga-keyboard-device.service` will get a few extra dependencies automatically:

```
Requires=sysinit.target
After=sysinit.target
After=basic.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Before=shutdown.target
```

See the paragraph on **Default Dependencies** in `man 5 systemd.service`.

A keyboard is initialized very early in the system start-up, because things like `cryptsetup.service` might need passphrases to be entered. Since you've specified your service should run `Before=keyboard-setup.service`, it gets placed very early indeed. But then the auto-generated default dependencies require it to be placed `After` both `sysinit.target` and `basic.target`, resulting in a loop.

So, you should study the flow diagram in `man 7 bootup`, and whenever you are writing a service that would be placed anywhere before `basic.target`, **remember to add `DefaultDependencies=no` to any such service.**

Comment: That makes sense, but know I am wondering if it needs any of the stuff that was turned off: specifically I think it needs to run after the code that generates `/dev/input/*`.

Comment: If it needs a particular `/dev/input/*` device, you could add an udev rule with a `TAG+="systemd"` for that device, and then you would have a `*.device` unit you could use in your dependencies.